# Novo Projeto - Usar Angular 1.x ou Angular2 + sparkjava + material design

Tags: angular, material-design

Gostaria de usar o angular2-material mas ainda não saiu, não posso adiar o projeto então tenho que escolher, duração do projeto uns 2 anos então ficar os próximos 2 anos no angular 1.x ou usar o angular 2 com o material design light? http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html " têm poucos componentes"

Projeto de 1 homem só, venho do asp classic, fazendo tudo no jquery+boostrap trazendo/levando json do/para o server e montando tudo no front tipo "SinglePage"

Abaixo exemplo de uma dessas porquice: "sempre tive orgulho" mas quando vi o poder do angular ai foi paixão pela milésima vista [ainda acho muito verboso] + 2 melhorou um pouco:

```js
/**
 * Form Submit
 * HTML exemplo:
 *  <form action="/login" method="post" data-submit> ... </form>
 * JS:
 *  $(function() {
 *   $('form[data-submit]').formSubmit({
 *    sucesso: function(resp){
 *      ... trata retorno aqui
 *     },
 *    falha: function(resp){
 *      ... tratar retorno aqui
 *     }
 *   });
 *  });
 */
$.fn.formSubmit = function(opt) {
     var form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
       type: form.attr('method'),
         url: form.attr('action'),
         data: form.serialize()
       }).done(function(resp) {
        // load function
        //console.log(resp);
        (opt.sucesso(resp));
       }).fail(function(resp) {
        // load function
        //console.log(resp);
        (opt.falha(resp));
       });
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Da forma como a sua pergunta esta neste momento, e muito provável que a comunidade a considere principalmente baseada em opiniões, isto e, cada um tem uma visão diferente sobre o que deve ser feito/usado. Edite a sua pergunta de forma a deixa-la mais objectiva e com um propósito bem definido. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como perguntar.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu também vim do bom e velho `jQuery`, migrando para o `AngularJs` sem chances de voltar atrás, antes de prosseguir com a resposta, gostaria de fazer uma pergunta, pois ela irá definir o rumo que - eu pelo menos - aconselho você a seguir.

#### Qual é o seu conhecimento de `AngularJs 1` hoje?

Se a resposta é qualquer coisa que não seja de avançado para cima, recomendo que você considere fortemente utilizar o `ng2.0` (ng = Angular). Digo isso por que a diferença entre `ng1` e `ng2` é muito gritante, em todos os aspectos. A grosso modo falando, é como se fossem 2 linguagens completamente diferentes. O modo como você programa em `ng1` e `ng2` possuem fundamentos semelhantes mas práticas diferentes. Por isso mais vale você começar e aprender o `ng2` do que iniciar no `ng1` pelo simples fato de possuir uma biblioteca visual de *material design*. Isso é apenas um detalhe.

*De que adianta um quadro bonito se você não tem casa para pendurar?*

O que você estaria perdendo caso não use `material2.0`, seriam apenas funcionalidades superficiais, como slide de `drawer`, `tooltip`, FAB, etc.. O que você estaria perdendo caso não use o `ng2`, seria performance, retardo tecnológico, simplicidade e organização de código, etc..

A balança pesa muito para um lado só.

Entendo quando você diz **Projeto de um homem só**, mas existem outras `frameworks` de *material design* que podem lhe proporcionar todo o aspecto visual, sem as funcionalidades superficiais, que também podem ser atingidas com `ng2` e animações `css3`. Podem não ser tão modulares, mas certamente suprem a sua necessidade.

---

Agora, se você já possui um bom conhecimento em `ng1`, não vejo problema em você continuar utilizando o mesmo. Por mais que o `ng2 beta` esteja ai, a versão 1 ainda terá um bom tempo de suporte, suficiente para migrarmos para  o `ng2` com mais tranquilidade e calma. Sem por os carros à frente dos bois. E ai sim, você pode usar as 2 bibliotecas para criar um projeto bem harmonioso.

Espero que a resposta possa esclarecer sua dúvida e lhe guiar melhor.

Comment: Obrigado, foi muito esclarecedor, pra frente é que se anda, vou caminhar nessa direção ng-2.

Comment: @EveraldoLima como eu já tenho uma base muito grande de projetos, ainda vou ficar no ng1.. Mas me dei um prazo de 6 meses pra começar a mudar.. É uma mudança muito grande e um aprendizado maior ainda. Mas certamente os benefícios são grandes também. =D Que bom que pude ajudar.